# I can't install R packages using install_github in RStudio

Tags: r, permissions, package

Whenever I try to install a package using `devtools:install_github()` in RStudio, I always get the following error

```
Error: ERROR: no permission to install to directory.....
```

Example: I tried installing abbrevTexts package from github because it isn't on CRAN

> devtools::install_github(repo =
> 'https://github.com/edvardoss/abbrevTexts')

```
install_github(repo = 'https://github.com/edvardoss/abbrevTexts')
Downloading GitHub repo edvardoss/abbrevTexts@HEAD

v  checking for file
'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpaYzhG4\remotes13087fd31b53\edvardoss-abbrevTexts-e1ced05/DESCRIPTION' (1.4s)
-  preparing 'abbrevTexts': (458ms)
v  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts (534ms)
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
     NB: this package now depends on R (>= 3.5.0)
     WARNING: Added dependency on R >= 3.5.0 because serialized objects in
     serialize/load version 3 cannot be read in older versions of R.
     File(s) containing such objects:
       'abbrevTexts/data/rawProducts.RData'
       'abbrevTexts/data/standardProducts.RData'
-  building 'abbrevTexts_0.1.0.tar.gz'
   
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Admin/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Error: ERROR: no permission to install to directory 'C:/Users/Admin/Documents/R/win-library/4.1'
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpaYzhG4/file13082b9f66da/abbrevTexts_0.1.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

I have tried updating permissions on every R folders but to no avail. I can install packages from CRAN using `install.packages()` easily and without problems

My `.libPaths()` shows 2 directories.

```
[1] "C:/Users/Admin/Documents/R/win-library/4.1"
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.0/library"
```

The first directory contains my packages.
Please I need to know if this is an R problem or Windows permission issue and how best to fix it. This issue is really affecting my productivity. Help is really needed.

1. R version 4.1.0
2. RStudio version 2022.02.3 Build 492
3. HP Windows 10

Comment: I'm on a macbook right now and cannot try and replicate, but have you tried launching RStudio as an admin? ie right click and select Run as administrator

Comment: I use Windows and I have tried running RStudio as an admin numerous times and still can't download packages from github

Comment: It worked for me on Win10, but I'm running R4.2.2. Even though abbrevTexts depends on >= 3.5.0, try updating R to the latest version to see if that helps.

Comment: How do I update my R version without losing my currently installed packages?

Comment: I basically reset my laptop (which in turn reset Windows permissions) and the problem was solved. I can now install packages using `install_github()` and `install _packages()`.
What a relief.